# SwiftUI on MacOS Floating Panel

Tags: macos, swiftui, panel, floating

I created a floating panel along AppDelegate in a style of MacOS spotlight.
The WindowGroup is empty.

```
@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) private var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
           // ContentView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar) // hide the window title bar using a built-in SwiftUI window style
        .windowToolbarStyle(.unifiedCompact)
                .commands {
                    SidebarCommands()
                        CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem, addition: { })
                    }
        
    }
```

The function "applicationDidFinishLaunching" inside AppDelegate starting with:

```
if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
                    window.close()
                }
```

to prevent the standard window view comes up and make the floating panel active with:

```
newPanel.orderFront(nil)
newPanel.makeKey()
```

With that, only the desired floating panel will be shown. But if i click again on the app button, an empty standard window comes up beside my floating panel.

I tried to giving back the focus to the floating panel (the "second app window" ?) , but i think the focus is not the problem. The panel should be the "one and only" window, focused or not.

The properties of the panel ("canBecomeKey" and "canBecomeMain") are set true.
I tried additional properties "isMainWindow" etc. but no luck.
I tried to add AppDelegate functions like "applicationDidUnhide" but this will not work too.

How can a set the floating panel to be the standard application window and make sure the app wont open a second?

Comment: Does this help? https://cindori.com/developer/floating-panel

Comment: unfortunately not. This example have a standard view and call a floating panel by a button - two windows. I want to have just one window - the panel. I can suppress the first window, as described, but each time i click again on the app symbol, the panel and the "standard view" appears.

Comment: One step further: i read the visible NSWindow after creating the Panel ```self.windowsAfterStart = NSApp.windows.filter {$0.isVisible}```. Then using applicationWillUpdate() to read the upcoming windows ```currentWindows = NSApp.windows.filter {$0.isVisible}``` If self.windowAfterStart.isEmpty --> currentWindows.close

Comment: @PeterDuckjibe Have you found a solution for your question? If so, could you post it as an answer?